# Authenticate Microsoft Teams Tab against external API

Tags: microsoft-teams, adal, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm working on a Teams Tab that requires access to my own external API, however I'm having difficulty understanding the best way to achieve authentication in the context of a Tab.

My API uses the standard OAuth2.0 workflow for getting an access token, but from the Teams Tab context it's unclear where I can safely store the access token after completing the OAuth flow. Also, I need to safely store the client secret for my API so that it's not visible in the client-side code.

So far I've tried using ADAL.js and the examples in https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-complete-node without any luck.

I'm assuming I need to authenticate my API through the Azure AD but I'm unable to find where I'd register the my API's client id/client secret to be used by the above libraries. Is there a standard pattern used by Teams developers to safely + securely handle this type of authentication?

Comment: There are many different questions you have. Where are your api's hosted? Are they in Azure environment? 
Are you facing any issues when trying out the sample code?
you can handle this through AD authentication.

Comment: @Abhijit-MSFT my API is hosted on my own server, outside of Azure. The issue I have with the samples is they don't provide an external API example.

When working with the Bot Framework I was able to set up an "Generic Oauth 2" service provider with my API's client secret + client id, then fetch an access token from the service provider when needed. But, I can't find an equivalent approach for Tabs.

So, what I'd like to know is if there is something similar for Teams Tabs where I can set up an OAuth provider (with my own API) and securely fetch access tokens when needed. Is that possible?

Comment: You can not set up oAuth provider for unknown application. It has to be registered with Azure AD. There are several third-party libraries in the open source community that abstract the OAuth 2.0 authentication process in every major programming language.

Comment: "You can not set up oAuth provider for unknown application. It has to be registered with Azure AD." That was the answer I was looking for. Thanks for the clarification @Abhijit-MSFT